# Background color for segmented control in IOS

Tags: colors, background, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control which needs to be **blue** when **selected**, and **white** when **unselected**. Im facing problems to set the tint color when unselected, as for some reason, it always turns out to be grey.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

The blue border is actually a UIView with some border color, and within it I stuck the segmented control. But I cant change the grey background ( which should be white ).

I tried doing all of this :

```
    sc.selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor.blue
    sc.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white], for: .selected)
    sc.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body),NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue], for: .normal)
    sc.tintColor = .white
    sc.backgroundColor = .white
    sc.isOpaque =  true
```

with no success. :(

Answer (score -1):

It's working fine with background color

```
self.backgroundColor = .red
```

It's working fine in iOS 13

Comment: The question was about setting of white background color. And in case of setting of pure colors - background appears as grey.